# Using data from JSON. Match and update word or sentence on a page to be Clickable to another website/page

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object containing words or a sentence that have corresponding URLs.

I need a way to match the words or sentence with whats on the same web page, then update the matching words or sentence to be a text link to the corresponding URLs. Lastly, if a match is found and the word or sentence is without an Url it's to display "coming soon" after the words or sentence.

Any help in pointing me in the right direction would be great. Many thanks in advance.

I've been looking at forums and other posts that are similar but have had no luck in finding an answer. I've asked other friends but still had no luck. I've attached some code I've found on what could be a starting point.

````
 input = input.replace(/<font span=([^<]+)<\/font>/gi, "<span class=$1</span>");
 return input;
}
function fixit() {
 document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = fixcode(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML);
} ```

Example JSON:

[{"name":"Product1","link":"www.cnn.com"},{"name":"Product2","link":"www.bbc.co.uk"},{"name":"Product3","link":""},{"name":"A few words ","link":"www.example.com"}]
````

Comment: "on any web page"?  Sounds like you're going to hit [same-origin-policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) issues

Comment: Is this a browser plugin of some sort?

Comment: Can you post a sample of the JSON? I'm assuming you retrieve the JSON via ajax and then want to do text replacements based on the JSON document.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all TextNodes in the document using the following piece of code

```
          var walker = document.createTreeWalker(
            document.body,
            NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
            null,
            false
          );
          while ((node = walker.nextNode()) !== null)
          {
            var words = node.nodeValue.match(/\s*\S+/g) || [];
            // you can now inspect each of the words - or use the nodeValue as a whole
          }
```

Of course this will fail if you have HTML tag(s) in the middle of a word - it will be considered as 2 words by the above code.

You can try `document.body.innerText` but it has inconsistent behavior - depending on the browser you may end up having the content of STYLE and SCRIPT tags included in the result. There is a very good blog post on this topic - http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/

Comment: That's brilliant thanks for Link and starting point I'll get reading  :-)